# "Неоприходаванная" или "не оприходованная"

Tags: частица-не

Как правильно писать: "неоприходаванная" или "не оприходованная" выручка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это явное причастие, а для раздельного написания частицы НЕ с причастием важно не столько наличие противопоставления, сколько наличие пояснительного слова или слов "вовсе не, далеко не, отнюдь не". Здесь нет пояснительного слова и т.д., поэтому слово "неоприходованная" пишется слитно.

Comment: А может, прилагательное. Какая касса(?) - неоприходаванная. Без контекста не определишь. См. в словаре: Бухг. Не подвергшийся оприходованию; неучтённый. Н-ые деньги. Н-ые материальные ценности.2. Шутл. Ещё не использованный, не израсходованный; целый. Н-ая бутылка водки.Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт С. А. Кузнецов. 1998

Comment: В отглагольном прилагательном на первом плане - качественный признак, а причастии - признак по действию. Неоприходованная выручка - это выручка, над которой не совершили соответствующего действия, никакого качественного отттенка я здесь не вижу

Answer (score 3):

Возможны оба варианта. "Не" пишется раздельно, если есть или подразумевается противопоставление, если нужно подчеркнуть отрицание.